# Scrapy - Enable Proxy on ImagesPipeline only

Tags: python, scrapy

Is it possible to enable a proxy for the ImagesPipeline only?  Meaning, I do not want to enable a proxy for the spider, but I do want the proxy when I download images yielded from the spider.

I am familiar with this section of the docs:  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware

but don't know how to implement it with the ImagePipeline.  I think I need to write a custom image pipeline discussed here:  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html?highlight=image%20download#module-scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images

But I'm not 100% sure.  Any feedback?

Comment: Unfortunately, Scrapy has no good mechanism for doing this. You'll have to override `get_media_requests` in your custom pipeline and manually set a proxy in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around it, by doing the opposite disabling the proxy for the spider requests with `dont_proxy` meta.

Answer (score 3):

For those of you looking at another answer, this code works to enable proxy in a custom image pipeline.

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        meta = {'proxy': 'http://192.168.1.1:80/'}
        for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            yield scrapy.Request(image_url, meta=meta)
```